# Searching by hash sha1 in bash script

Tags: bash, search, sha1

How to use command *find* to search for a file by  **hash sha1** in bash script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `find` doesn't have an option to check the SHA1 of a file natively, you can make find execute `sha1sum` for each file it finds and then use `grep` to pick the check sum you are looking for. For example:

```
find . -type f -exec sha1sum '{}' ';' | grep 7ceeeeaba7d7e22301dfc5d6707f0c7f3eeb55a8
```